# What happens if we rotate one gear and this rotates another and this to another and so on. Will the last gear rotate faster than light?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, experimental-physics

what happens if we rotate a small gear attached to a larger one and the large one rotates another small one attached to a large one and the large one rotates another small attached to a large one and so on
Will the last gear rotate faster than light?

Answer (score 3):

No. Rigidity in the sense that is frequently assumed in Newtonian mechanics breaks down in special relativity. A torque applied to a gear at one point doesn't immediately start turning each point in the gear at the same angular velocity. The "information" propagates in the form of small deformations within the gear, roughly at the speed of sound, which is less than the speed of light.